# В верстке появился символ, которого в ней нет

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Добрый день. Верстаем проект для личных целей и в мобильной версии между блоками на некоторых страницах проявляется цифра "1". Причем нигде в верстке найти его не удалось.
[image: сама неведомая цифра]

Методом поочередного исключения было выявлено, что символ идет от файла с "header"ом. Но его там нет, прикрепляю окончание файла.

```
  <li><a href="partners_program.php">Партнерская программа</a>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contacts.php ">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </header>
    <!---->
```

На странице отсутствует динамическая активность и не вызываются всяческие php-скрипты, которые могли дать единичку.
Все js-скрипты так же были проверены на наличие таких выводов.
Может быть кто-то сталкивался?

Comment: Прошу скинуть проект целиком иначе непонятно

Comment: Вы смешивали php код с html?

Comment: php код исключительно на уровне require_once блоков заголовка и подвала

Comment: Однако вы отчасти правы. Попробовал убрать require и вставить непосредственно код - единица пропала.
А в чем тогда проблема с requre?

Comment: Попробуйте по каждому файлу проекта нажать <kbd>ctrl + f</kbd> и найти это злорадную еденицу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Не обратил внимание , что вместо require_once  писал местами echo require_once

Comment: И такие нелепые ошибки бывают